# aws lambda: invoke function via other lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, invoke

I have an AWS Lambda function, that need's ~ 30 seconds.
When I connect it to the API Gateway, it's sending a 504 because of the 5 second timeout. So my easyCron Job is failing and will not try it again (I only have a free plan)

So I need an API, that sends a correct 200 status.
My Idea:

Invoke the long term lambda via a short term lambda.
The policy is allowing the invocation.

Here is the code

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),

 params = {
  FunctionName: 'cctv',
  InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
  LogType: 'Tail'
 },
 lambda;
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
 'use strict';
 lambda.invoke(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err, err.stack);
  }
  else {
   console.log(data);
  }
 });
 context.succeed('hey cron job, I think my lambda function is not called');

};
```

But I think, `context.succeed()` aborts the execution of `lambda.invoke()`

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You're not actually calling the code that calls your Lambda function. You're defining a function to do the work into `exports.handler`, but that's not being called.

Comment: This code is called by the API gateway. It's printing the succeed message, but it's not invoking the second lambda function 'cctv'

Comment: Yes, because the code you listed above is not actually calling `lambda.invoke`. So your level 1 function is being called, but your level 1 function is not actually calling your level 2 function.

Comment: I connected API Gateway with the first Lamba Function. It's calling the handler().
I thinks it's more or less this code:

`require('./index').handler({},{succeed:function(message){
    console.log(message);
},'error':function(){}});`

So I guess `lambda.invoke()`should be called

Comment: Can you show the complete level 1 source code?

Comment: `AWS.Lambda.invoke` nature is asynchronous. Call `context.success` within `lambda.invoke` callback function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is incorrect

```
InvocationType: 'RequestResponse'
```

You should use

```
InvocationType: 'Event'
```

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html#API_Invoke_RequestSyntax

> By default, the Invoke API assumes "RequestResponse" invocation type. You can optionally request asynchronous execution by specifying "Event" as the InvocationType.

Comment: Thank you! With InvocationType: 'Event' I get a 202! :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than directly calling your 30+ second Lambda function, you could trigger it from an SNS or S3 PutObject event.  This would be asynchronous to your API Gateway route, so it can return very quickly.  Of course, you would not have the outcome of the Lamdba job at that time.